# Can not read property 'Symbol (Symbol.iterator)' of undefined (Recursive function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, reactjs

I'd like to do a recursive function. Indeed, I would like each time that the id of an item corresponds to the id of a theme or sub-theme, I would like to insert the item in question in the child of the theme or sub-theme:
This is my function:

```
getItemByTheme=(item, themes, tab)=>{
  for(let theme of themes){
    if(theme.THEMEID === item.THEMEID ){
      item.PARENTID = theme.PARENTID;
      theme.children.push(item)
      return [true, [...tab, theme]]
    } else {
      let childItem =  this.getItemByTheme(item,theme.children, [...tab, theme]); 
      console.log(childItem)
    }
  }
  return [false, tab]
}
```

The first condition (if) works, but in the condition (else) it does not work, it returns an error:

> Can not read property 'Symbol (Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

I do not understand where the error comes from.

Comment: **By far** the best way to figure this out isn't posting a question on SO, it's using the debugger built into your environment (the one in your IDE, Node's built-in one that uses Chrome as its UI, your browser's built-in one, etc.) to step through the code statement by statement, looking at the values of your variables and parameters, etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses an iterator on both `themes` (`for(let theme of themes)`) and `tab` (`...tab` in two places), but when you make the recursive call, you don't pass anything for the `tab` parameter, and so it's `undefined`. `undefined` doesn't have an iterator.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. because by default when I call my function, the tab parameter is an empty array:               this.getFlowByTheme(item, themes[0], [])

Comment: @DeGiovanni: Yes. And then within it you call `this.getItemByTheme(item,theme.children, [...tab, theme]);`. Within that call, `tab` will be `undefined`. You've only passed two arguments, but `getItemByTheme` takes and uses *three* parameters.

Comment: And suddenly I have to do what to pass a value tab parameter, because I do not always see what's my mistake. :(